# Removing trailing slash at the end of file names in a folder

Tags: trailing-slash, trailing

Removing trailing slash at the end of file names in a folder

http://www.example.com/directory/index.php/ should return to http://www.example.com/directory/index.php  (that is without trailing slash at the end - it can be any file type like html, php, asp )

I tried with RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L] , but when some one type the url with slash at the end it redirects to http://www.example.com/file which should be returned as http://www.example.com/directory/index.php

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will never be able to handle every kind of bad typing. You can handle the very case with something like ^(.*?\.[a-z]{3,4})/$ $1 [R=301, L] but this would be just scratching the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your "web.config". 
It should be a "redirect" action not a "rewrite" as follows (It worked well for me):

```
            <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">  
                <match url="(.*)/$" />  
                <conditions>  
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />  
                </conditions>  
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />  
            </rule>
```

Hope this help you too.

Comment: This fixes single occurrences. I have a case where google is seeing "example.php/example2.php. How do I remove everything after the trailing slash?